# Derivative of an Inverse, Can't find Inverse

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, inverse-function

Taken from a single variable calc book.

*Find $g'(a)$, where g is the inverse function of the given function*

$f(x)=x^5-x^3+2x, a=2$

I intend to use the formula $g'(a)=\frac{1}{f'(g(a))}$, and I know that $f$ has an inverse. Obviously, $f'(x)=5x^4-3x^2+2$, but I can't seem to find $g$. Here's what I tried

$$y=x^5-x^2+2x$$
$$y+x^2=x^5+2x$$
$$(y+x^2)^{\frac{1}{5}}=(x^5+2x)^{\frac{1}{5}}$$

After this, I couldn't decide on an optimal way to proceed. I know that the binomial theorem extends to non-integer values, but I feel that this would be overkill for the problem...is it? Is there a simple way to find this inverse, or do I have to work my way through some nasty algebra? Thanks

***Edit: it was just made clear to me that I overlooked the obvious and forgot that $g(2) \implies f(x) = 2$; however, I am still curious as to how to find the inverse of the given function.***

Comment: The inversion is possible using Bring radicals and transformations to the principal quintic form, however these are really cumbersome to write down explicitly. If you really care about the answer, post a new question and add a bounty to it so that there's incentive to perform such a long calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to know the inverse for that particular value. Let's find $x=g(2)\iff f(x)=2$:

$$f(x)=2\Rightarrow x^5-x^3+2x-2=(x^4+x^3+2)(x-1)=0\Rightarrow x=1$$

since $f'(x)>0~~\forall~ x$ and thus it is invertible and attains each real number as a value only once. We have that $g(2)=1$ and finally we can calculate the derivative to be

$$g'(2)=\frac{1}{f'(g(2))}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Wow, what a novel solution. Great job, but now I'm curious -- how DO you find the inverse of the given function?

Comment: There's no reason in general to believe that an elementary function has an inverse that is also an elementary function.

Comment: It is generally hard to find analytic inverses to fifth order polynomials (at least in terms of radicals). It is a very well known theorem proven by E. Galois.

Comment: Yes, I have heard of that. So, is it safe to assume the inverse is a non-elementary function?

Comment: https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Functions/Functions.faq.question.753763.html

Comment: I think you want $x^4+x^3+2$ rather than $x^4+x^3-2$.

Comment: Thanks! edited.

Answer (score 1):

To find $g(2) = f^{-1}(2)$, we solve the following:
\begin{align}
0=x^5-x^3+2x-2 &= x^3(x+1)(x-1)+2(x-1)\\
&=(x^4+x^3+2)(x-1).
\end{align}
Clearly, $x^4+x^3>0$ for all $x\notin[-1,0]$, and hence,  $x^4+x^3+2>0$ in that interval. Also, for $x\in[-1,0]$, $x^4,x^3>-1$, and thus, $x^4+x^3+2>0$.

Therefore, $g(2)=1$.